# What's the correct way to stop a background process on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, daemon, user-agent

I have an application with 2 components: a desktop application that users interact with, and a background process that can be enabled from the desktop application.  Once the background process is enabled, it will run as a user launch agent independently of the desktop app.

However, what I'm wondering is what to do when the user *disables* the background process.  At this point I want to stop the background process but I'm not sure what the best approach is.  The 3 options that I see are:

1. Use the 'kill' command.

   - Direct, but not reliable and just seems somewhat "wrong".
2. Use an NSMachPort to send an exit request from the desktop app to the background process.

   - This is the best approach I've thought of but I've run into an implementation problem (I'll be posting this in a separate query) and I'd like to be sure that the approach is right before going much further.
3. Something else???

Thank you in advance for any help/insight that you can offer.

Comment: hooray for programs that let users turn off (sometimes) unwanted background processes!

Comment: I figured out my implementation problem with NSMachPort before I got to post the query.  It turns out that NSMachBootstrapServer doesn't like registering a port that is init'ed with a specific port number.  When I used the default init call, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The daemon could handle quit apple events or listen on a CFMessagePort.

If you use signals you should handle the signal, probably SIG_QUIT, that is sent instead of just letting the system kill your process.

If you have cleanup that may take a while, use something other than signals.  If you are basically just calling exit, then signals are fine.

If you already have a CFRunLoop going then use CFMessagePort.  If you are already handling apple events than handle quit.

CFMessagePort is a wrapper around CFMachPort that provides a name and some other conveniences.  You can also use the NS wrappers for either.

Comment: Thank you!  Since I've got an NSRunLoop going I'll be sticking with NSMachPort.  I looked into NSMessagePort but the current Apple <a href="http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMessagePort_Class/Reference/Reference.html">documentation</a> tells developers to avoid its use in favour of NSMachPort and that it may be deprecated soon.

Comment: Thank you! Since I've got an NSRunLoop going I'll be sticking with NSMachPort. I looked into NSMessagePort but the current Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMessagePort_Class/Reference/Reference.html) tells developers to avoid its use in favour of NSMachPort and that it may be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do this using an NSConnection object.  I created a very simple ExitListener object with this header:

```
@interface ExitListener : NSObject {
    BOOL _exitRequested;
    NSConnection *_connection;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL exitRequested;

- (void)requestExit;

@end
```

and this implementation:

```
@implementation ExitListener

@synthesize exitRequested = _exitRequested;

// On init we set ourselves up to listen for an exit
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init]) != nil) {
        _connection = [[NSConnection alloc] init];

        [_connection setRootObject:self];
        [_connection registerName:@"com.blahblah.exitport"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_connection release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)requestExit {
    [self setExitRequested:YES];
}

@end
```

To setup the listener, the background process simply allocates and inits an instance of the ExitListener.  The desktop application then asks the background process to exit by making this call:

```
- (void)stopBackgroundProcess {
    // Get a connection to the background process and ask it to exit
    NSConnection *connection = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"com.blahblah.exitport" host:nil];
    NSProxy *proxy = [connection rootProxy];
    if ([proxy respondsToSelector:@selector(requestExit)]) {
        [proxy performSelector:@selector(requestExit)];
    }
}
```

Using NSMachPorts directly seemed to lead to far more problems in registering and obtaining references.  I found that NSConnection is the simplest way to create a basic communication channel for the sort of situation that I needed to solve.